# Static width in text field

Tags: ios, storyboard, width, textfield

please how can i have a static width for my Text Fields.

I have a Login View Controller (portrait) in which i have an image (logo of the App), username text field, password text field and a button to log in.

When i run it in an Iphone it looks pretty good, but in Ipad all looks stretched. 
[image: Iphone]

[image: ipad]

What can i do so this elements looks the same in both devices? (i want them to look as the Iphone shows).
I don't want them to resize. 
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If you want an element to be an exact size you would update the width and height constraints to be your desired number.

Comment: But text field has a specific height which is 30.

Comment: Since your width is not static your are getting a skew because your aspect ratio is getting off.

try and set a static width or adjust the display properties to not try and keep your aspect ratio the same.

Comment: In "add new constrainst" from the options that are below i check the width and height, that is what i should do or not? Thanks!

Comment: I would do that and see how you feel about the look you are going for, if you don't like the look of that you can then play with the aspect ratio constraint or read more about the inspector options regarding height/width setting.

Answer (score 0):

Set your textFields width and height properties to your desired size in Attributes inspector panel or do it programmatically.

I would recommend you to use Auto Layout as that will help you make your design beautiful in all resolutions and sizes.

Comment: in text field the height is 30 and is blocked, i can't change it :/

Comment: TextFields height can't change, you can only change the length. If you want taller you would need to add a textarea instead.

Comment: Textfield height can change but for now just fix the width by adding a constraint on width for textfield

Comment: Well you can change the height by setting height constraint for it, but it's recommended by design that it is 30.

Comment: In "add new constrainst" from the options that are below i check the width and height, that is what i should do or not? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your answer, i erase the "Leading space to container" and "Trailing space to container" in each one of the elements.
It is no resizing anymore :)